# Convert string to mysql datetime with AM/PM

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, datetime

I am working on a WordPress plugin that allows the user to select a time using a jQuery dropdown script. The time is a string in the format of "5 : 34 PM". I need to save that value to my mysql database in the datetime format.

So far, I can save the date and time but the AM/PM is not being factored in.

Here is my PHP function:

```
function db_tables_insert() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'tweettweet';
    $tweet = $_POST["tweet"];
    $time = $_POST["timepicker"];
    $time=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $time);
    $date = "2015-02-08:";
    $datetime = $date.$time;

    $wpdb->insert( 
        $table_name, 
        array( 
            'time' => $datetime,
            'text' => $tweet, 
        ) 
    );
}
```

In this example, the value saved to the database would be "2015-02-08 12:13:00" (assuming the user selected 12:13 for the time). The problem is, that value is the same whether the user selects 12:13 am or 12:13 pm.

I need a way to convert the string so that the "am/pm" is taken into consideration when saved to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime` should be able to handle this.

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('2014-12-12 12:34 AM'));
```

returns `2014-12-12 00:34:00`

Comment: Ok so how would I integrate that into my code? This doesn't seem to work: $newdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($datetime));

Comment: Change these two lines.

    `$date = "2015-02-08";` and 
    `$datetime = $date. ' ' .$time;`